# Seach and replace with special characters

Tags: substitute

I am trying a search and replace because I am using some macros in my code. 
I want to replace  `tb.DUT.genblk4[0].U_rap_cisfd_wrapper` this with `` `RAP_CISFD_WRAP_I ``
in vim.

I tried using

```
:%s/tb\.DUT\.genblk4[0\]\.U_rap_cisfd_wrapper/`RAP_CISFD_WRAP_I/gc
```

But it is saying pattern not found. Help?

Sample code:

```
begin   

    force tb.DUT.genblk4[0].U_rap_cisfd_wrapper.agent_ops_mem_inst_0.u_ops_mem.wbe_a = 8'hFF;
    force tb.DUT.genblk4[0].U_rap_cisfd_wrapper.agent_ops_mem_inst_0.u_ops_mem.wr_rd_en_a = 1'b1;
    force tb.DUT.genblk4[0].U_rap_cisfd_wrapper.agent_ops_mem_inst_0.u_ops_mem.addr_a = 15'h0000 + 15'h1*d0;
    force tb.DUT.genblk4[0].U_rap_cisfd_wrapper.agent_ops_mem_inst_0.u_ops_mem.data_inp_a = data_ops;
    d0=d0+1;
    @(posedge tb.DUT.genblk4[0].U_rap_cisfd_wrapper.agent_ops_mem_inst_0.u_ops_mem.clk);
end
```

Comment: related : https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/17465/how-to-search-literally-without-any-regex-pattern

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to also escape the `[` character otherwise Vim consider it as the beginning of the `/[]` pattern atom which create a group containing the characters between `[` and `]`

```
%s;tb\.DUT\.genblk4\[0\]\.U_rap_cisfd_wrapper;`RAP_CISFD_WRAP;gc
```